# Running a REST service on a different port as part of same server

Tags: jax-rs, guice

I have application server using guice for dependency injection and jaxrs for REST.

```
public final class MyWebServer {
  public void start() {
    ...
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creates an injector that has all the necessary dependencies needed to
    // build a functional server.
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
        new RequestLoggingModule(),
        new RequestHandlerModule(),
        new AuthenticationModule(),
        new DatabaseModule(),
        ...);
    // Bootstrap the application by creating an instance of the server then
    // start the server to handle incoming requests.
    injector.getInstance(MyWebServer.class)
        .start();
  }
}
```

This server instance runs on port 8080. I want to run another lightweight service that runs on this server but runs on a different port (for e.g. 9090). I thought of a way of achieving the same like

replace this single call of

```
 injector.getInstance(MyWebServer.class)
        .start();
```

by a thread for each of

```
new Thread(()-> {//code that starts MyWebServer }).run()
new Thread(()-> {//code that starts Another server }).run()
```

But in this approach I end up creating a new server. Is there any way of configuring the port for specific for a module and running it as a lightweight service inside same server?